# Jenkins: Tracing the history of unsaved new test definition (copied from another test definition)?

Tags: jenkins

Recently, in our enterprise production setup, it seems someone has tried to setup a new job / test definition by using another (copying) from identical job. However, (s)he seems to have NOT saved (and probably, am guessing here, closed the browser with the session being lost).

But the new job got saved though it was not set to stable or active; we knew about this because changes uploaded to gerrit, started failing in this newly setup partial job (because, these changes were in certain repos that met certain TDD settings).

Question: Jenkins system does not have trace of who setup the system in 'configure versions' option. Is there anyway to know the details of who setup the job / when was that done ?

Comment: I noted that the question in the topic and the question in the body text are not really the same. Would you mind updating either one with what you're after?

Comment: @David Pärsson: You are correct, I made the change to question header

Answer (score 1):

No, Jenkins does not store that information by default.

If your Jenkins instance happen to be running behind an Apache or Nginx web server, there might be access logs that can help you. To find out when the job was created you could look at when its `config.xml` file was created/modified.

However, there are a few plugins that can add this functionality so that you won't have this problem again:

- [JobConfigHistory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) – Tracks changes in your job configurations and gives the ability to restore old versions.
- [Audit Trail Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin) – Keeps a log of who performed particular Jenkins operations, such as configuring jobs.

Comment: Thanks very much for the details and info about the plugins. Other than the 'config.xml' are there any other known or undocumented ways to trace the activity or event ?

Comment: What activity or event are you referring to? Jenkins exposes its API, so it's possible to interact with it using both Groovy scripts and HTTP requests.